# jQuery: trying to get the input value

Tags: jquery, input, get

i'm trying to obtain an input value with this:

```
var $a = ('#telephone_number').val();

alert($a);
```

But nothing, any idea?

**telephone_number** is the id of the input.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 7):

use this

```
var $a = jQuery('#telephone_number').val();
```

OR

```
var $a = $('#telephone_number').val();
```

Comment: Thaqt's the same code as the OP has, which doesn't work for him. There's something else wrong.

Comment: @GenericTypeTea:  OP is missing the `$` to signify a JQuery function call which is why it's not working.

Comment: @JungleFeak - O yeah :). Sorry! +1

Answer (score 0):

```
   var $a = $('#telephone_number').val();

    alert($a);
```

currently you are not passing the div id to jQuery, u are just doing **(#tel_no)** this is wrong.