# how to get value out of input text in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to get the value of the userinput, but my code isn't working properly.

html

```
<body>
<button id="test">test</button>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="test1">
</form>
</body>
```

javascript:

```
var text = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    text = $("#test1").value;
    $("#test").on("click", testing);

});

function testing(){
    console.log("something");
    if(text == "top"){
        console.log("top");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: trying to get the input value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788910/jquery-trying-to-get-the-input-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**:

```
text = $("#test1").val();
```

Also you need to move above line inside your `testing` function to make it check the value of your input when the button clicked. So final code look like:

```
var text = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", testing);
});

function testing(){
    console.log("something");
    text = $("#test1").val();
    if(text == "top"){
        console.log("top");
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XCLdP/)**

Answer (score 0):

in jQuery it's [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), not `value`, which works on native DOM nodes only

```
text = $("#test1").val();
```

And there's really no need for globals here, and you should make sure the value is updated when clicking the button, right now it's only stored on DOM ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").on("click", testing);
});

function testing(){
    var text = $("#test1").val();

    if(text == "top"){
        console.log("top");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this will work

```
$("#test").click(function(){
     var value = $("#test1").val();
     alert(value); check value by alert
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method** in jQuery

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/37YPC/)**

```
 text = $("#test1").val();
```